# In flex How to create a trapezoid shape with the Class of Matrix?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I want to use Image Reflection in trapezoid shape. That why i ask how to create trapezoid shape with the class of matrix

Comment: Could you please provide more of description of what exactly you want to do?  Mainly, I don't understand why you need or want to use the Matrix class.  Are you planning on using the Matrix to transform the view of other components?  If you only want to draw a trapezoid, that can be done as a graphics primitive, eg., extend the FilledElement class and override the draw(g:Graphics) method, just like the spark.primitives.Rect class does.

Comment: I want to use Image Reflection in trapezoid shape. That why i ask how to create trapezoid shape with the class of matrix.

Comment: Copy pasting what you just said is not really going to help, you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For *shear* mathematical reasons you can't achieve this with the Matrix class per se.

However, the effect you are looking to achieve, i.e., having an image or component reflection look as though it has 3D perspective, can be achieved as long as you are compiling for Flash Player 10, or greater.  You can do this using the [Matrix3D](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix3D.html) class, which allows you to affect pseudo-3D transformations (projective transformations) in Flash.

**Example**

In the MXML:

```
<mx:Image id="img" source="@Embed('image.jpg')"/>
<mx:Image id="reflection" source="{img.source}"
          creationComplete="reflectImage()"/>
```

and in the script block:

```
protected function reflectImage():void
{
    var m3D:Matrix3D = new Matrix3D();
    m3D.appendScale(1,-1,-1);  // flip the image
    m3D.appendTranslation(0,img.height,0);  // move it back to (0,0,0)
    m3D.appendRotation(-45, Vector3D.X_AXIS); // rotate it (this gives it the trapezoid shape)
    m3D.appendTranslation(0,img.height,0);  // move to the bottom of "img"

    reflection.transform.matrix3D = m3D;    
}
```

You'll probably want to play with the numbers a bit to affect the look you're going for, but this is the way to go about it.

**Note**: Any transformations (like setting x, y ) in the MXML will be overridden by the `reflectImage` function.